# MPMoviePlayerController spams 'Received memory warning'

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm adding a `MPMoviePlayerController` as background view and while it plays I get spams of the log-message 'Received memory warning'. I don't now why, and maybe there is a workaround or a better solution.

**Here is my code:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[self navigationController]setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    [moviePlayer play];

}

- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [moviePlayer pause];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor appStyleLightOrangeColor];

    //Add Video playback
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"happy-female-friends-smartphon" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    moviePlayer.fullscreen =  YES;
    moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    //set the frame of movie player
    moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;


    [self.view insertSubview:moviePlayer.view atIndex:0];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(appBecameActive)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [self performSelector:@selector(animationCode) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
}

-(void)appBecameActive{
    [moviePlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thannks first to @tdevoy for your advices.

I finally got rid of the warning. It was the file type! I had to convert it to `.3gp`and now it works much smoother and without warnings.

On strange thing is I even use now 4mb more memory than before. But everything works great..

Answer (score 1):

The log says it all. You are receiving a printed warning that you are using too much memory and your app will shutdown if you do not free up space. You need to take immediate steps to lower your memory line, so don't just shrug off those warnings. Yeah, your app might not crash immediately, but it is often a sign of a much bigger problem in your code setup.

Run the Allocations Instrument in XCode to see where the bulk of your memory is being used. I'd first check the size of that m4v video also. You should be streaming the video if it is a significant size. Additionally, ensure that you are not leaking memory using the Leaks instrument. But once again, when you receive the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` callback, take immediate action. Either pick up the notification in the `AppDelegate` or subscribe to the `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` and release items/viewControllers that can be recreated later.

Here's the [Memory Management Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MemoryManagement.html) if you want to consult.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll explain my situation: It's my welcome screen (similar to Spotify) with a few login buttons. The Video (28.3mb) is playing over and over again. So I can't really stream it, right?

Comment: No prob. But haha yeah that's pretty huge. You could consider animating images of the video (depending on complexity of video) instead. If it's completely necessary though, then look for other views currently living that don't need to be or items in your bundle that you can remove.

Comment: Well as you said, that its kinda huge, I went and rechecked the codec.  I played a bit with the quality and now it looks good and its at 4mb. Is it still big?

Comment: Yeah, that shouldn't cause you any issues (unless you have tons of other large items in your bundle). But if you still get the warning, run Instruments and inspect that your not leaking.

Comment: I'm still getting the warning.. Can you recommend a good tutorial how to you the instrument tool?

Comment: Check this one out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html